# Countdown the chances in loop for guessing game

Tags: python, loops

I made five chances for the guesser to guess the random number. Every time the guesser did wrong, I want to print:

`Nice try, guess again (try bigger), you get {x} chance left.`

The `x` is a countdown, so the first wrong guess will say you get 4 chances left, then another wrong, three chances left, and so on. How can I do that? Or, how to add a loop on the x.

So this is my unsuccessful code:

```
import random

secret_num = random.randint(1, 20)

print('Guess the number from 1-20 (you get 5 chances)')

for guess_chance in range(1, 6):
    guess = int(input("Input guess number: "))

    if guess < secret_num:
        x = 5
        x -= 1
        print(f'Nice try, guess again (try bigger), you get {x} chance left.')

    elif guess > secret_num:
        x = 5
        x -= 1
        print(f'Nice try, guess again (try smaller), you get {x} chance left.')

    else:
        break

if guess == secret_num:
    print('Congratz, you guess correctly in' + str(guess_chance) + 'times.')
else:
    print('Nope, the correct number is ' + str(secret_num) + '.')
```

Comment: you need to do `x=5` before `for guess_chance in range...`) and remove it from inside the loop

Comment: You could do a reverse range instead and use `guess_chance` directly, e.g. `for guess_chance in range(5, 0, -1)): ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `x = 5` before for `guess_chance in range...`) and remove it from inside the loop.

```
print('Guess the number from 1-20 (you get 5 chances)')

x = 5

for guess_chance in range(1, 6):
    guess = int(input("Input guess number: "))

    if guess < secret_num:
        x -= 1
        print(f'Nice try, guess again (try bigger), you get {x} chance left.')

    elif guess > secret_num:
        x -= 1
        print(f'Nice try, guess again (try smaller), you get {x} chance left.')

    else:
        break
```

Otherwise, each guess you are resetting it to 5 tries and then subtracting one... which presumably always shows 4 tries...

There are many other ways to solve this... I just picked the one that changed your code the least

and when combined with your range this is a bit redundant

`x = 6 - guess_chance` would work

as would just iterating the range in reverse